# Trying to capture PointerEntered event inside InkCanvas in UWP App

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am creating a UWP application for a tablet and I need to capture the PointerEntered event within the InkCanvas element, but for some reason I do not know it does not work.

I have tried different things but none has worked for me. I tryed with another methods like PointerMoved and this works for me. The InkCanvas element is inside a Canvas Element.

```
<Canvas Name="CNVSignatura" Opacity="0.8" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="235" Margin="810,150,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="450" Background="White">
        <InkCanvas x:Name="INKSignatura" Margin="0,0,0,0" PointerEntered="canvas_Focus" Height="235" Width="450"/>
</Canvas>
```

If I debug the code, I can verify that the canvas_Focus method is never called

**Edit**: I assign the input type and then i applied thee method described in the [Event Handlers not working with inkCanvas in Windows Universal App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38467349/event-handlers-not-working-with-inkcanvas-in-windows-universal-app/38467760#38467760). Here's my code:

```
INKSignatura.InkPresenter.InputDeviceTypes = CoreInputDeviceTypes.Touch | CoreInputDeviceTypes.Mouse;
CoreInkIndependentInputSource core = CoreInkIndependentInputSource.Create(INKSignatura.InkPresenter);
core.PointerEntering += Core_PointerEntering;
```

I use the PointerEntered event but when I click on inkcanvas it returns an exception "System.NotImplementedException: 'The method or operation is not implemented.'"

Comment: Did you mention Input Type? see [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38467760/4585476)

Comment: Yes, look at the edit. Thanks!

Comment: Please avoid add `throw new NotImplementedException();` in the `Core_PointerEntering`.

Comment: Thanks! Finally this solved my problem.

Comment: May I convert this comment as an answer for this case ?

Comment: Yes! But only for this case.